# Changing disable flag in ng-options causes select to be unlselected

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Example of the problem:

https://embed.plnkr.co/5MSJB9E7AMNDF5oZQJRR/

When that is loaded, `h` is selected even though its disabled. This is fine and expected.

Next, if you selected a non-disabled value, let's say `d`. That works.

But once you click the button to flip the `disable` boolean, the model gets set to `null` and the select loses what's selected.

You can even flip the boolean for the initially selected value to not be disabled and the value stays, but then flip it again and it gets lost.

Is this expected? It doesn't seem that this should happen to me since the first use case allows it to be selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the same question in the Angular github issue tracker and found out this behavior is by design. For me, that was good enough and we'll come up with another way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

*"But once you click the button to flip the disable boolean, the model gets set to null and the select loses what's selected."*

Your `selected` variable evaluates to `null`, because in filter you have `disable when option.disable`. So there is no selected value after switching `disable` property to `true`, and it evaluates to `null`. But you can fix that by selecting another one option, by click, for example, or programmatically (i think it would be the better way).

I have added the automatic selection of none-disabled option after disabling another one, here is the working plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/hr7aM1WXKlgRaEm8qwit?p=preview

Or if you just want to display something like "Select an option" when nothing is selected - here is another plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/vttB1U5QTBts3O8clQfG?p=preview